# Dudas c# acerca de Listbox y FileCopy

Tags: c#

Tengo un par de dudas acerca de recoger las rutas completas de selecciones en un listbox y copiar el archivo usando esa misma ruta. Las listo dejo separadas para no abrir mas preguntas relacionadas con la misma aplicacion que estoy creando.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;

        //Cerrar Outlook antes de copiar
        //killOutlook();

        //Recorrer en un for los elementos seleccionados

        
        // Determine if there are any items checked.  
        if (checkedListBox.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            // If so, loop through all checked items and print results.  
            
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                string path_item = Path.GetFullPath(checkedListBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(path_item);


                //Copiar rutas a current directory File.Copy
                File.Copy(path_item,currectDirectory);
            }

        }
```

1. Tengo una aplicacion que lista archivos de una determinada extension y los muestra en un listbox.
   Despues selecciono los que necesito y deberia copiarlos a una ubicacion.

el caso es que al seleccionar los items que necesito copiar, los muestro en un MessageBox para asegurarme que las rutas las recoge correctamente, pero no es asi.
Siempre me muestra el ultimo item seleccionado repetidas veces, segun los items que he seleccionado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Cuando le doy al boton "Backup PST" deberia recoger las rutas de los items seleccionados y mediante la funcion File.Copy(origen,destino) deberia copiarmelo.
   Pero me da un error que me indica qwue no puede encontrar ese archivo, pero existe en esa ubicacion que me devuelve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que añadas el código por escrito ya que es mas fácil para nosotros emular tu problema y por los daltónicos de nuestra comunidad, puedes hacerlo pulsando [edit]

Comment: Si, perdona ya esta editado.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Deberías añadir el código de como llenas la ListBox para ver exactamente que valor estás poniendo en cada item de la lista y asi poder saber nosotros también de donde puede venir el problema.

Comment: @Marc Ya esta pegado en el mensaje principal.
Gracias

Comment: @AntonioCastilloMoreno Con mensaje principal te refieres a otra pregunta diferente a esta? Si es así, deberías poner el enlace ya que si alguien entra aqui sin saber que ya habias publicado una pregunta no lo va a saber (que ha sido mi caso)

Comment: Tambien estaría bien que pusieras el error que te da entero y el valor que tiene `currentDirectory` cuando llega allí

Comment: @Marc Esta el codigo de la funcion donde problemas en esta misma pagina. En mi pregunta.
No puedo copiarlo en este mensaje por la limitacion de caracteres.

CurrentDirectory es la misma ubicacion donde se encuentra el .exe. Lo tengo asi para hacer pruebas y no complicarme mucho.

Los items de la lista los recoge haciendo una busqueda por todo el disco de los archivos con extension .pst y los llena en el listbox

String currectDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127057/discussion-between-antonio-castillo-moreno-and-marc).

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta aquí

```
 string path_item = Path.GetFullPath(checkedListBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Estas cogiendo solamente el nombre del archivo que es el del item seleccionado, pero realmente tienes que coger la ruta, vaya "C:\Programa\nombredeArchivo.jpg" eso lo podrías mirar con el AppContext.BaseDirectory o puede ser el AplicationContext. Mira que tipo de Context esta usando tu aplicación y a partir de allí podrás construir la ruta.

Para realizar el copiar pegar o mover archivos lo mismo no es solamente pasar el nombre del archivo es requerido todo el path entero. Espero que te ayude la info

Comment: Entiendo que estoy recogiendo la ruta completa tal como se ve en la imagen no?
Podrias corregirme el codigo en tal caso?
Muchas gracias

Comment: El currentdirectory que valor tiene ? haber si va a ser el destino lo que te esta fallando

Answer (score 0):

Según los comentarios que hemos intercambiado y analizando el código que estás usando, creo que el problema proviene de la línea.

```
File.Copy(path_item, currentDirectory)
```

Si leemos la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=net-5.0) de esta función nos dice que los parámetros que acepta son `Archivo origen, Archivo destino`, y en tu caso le estás pasando `Archivo origen, Carpeta destino`.

Deberías pasarle a la función la ruta entera del archivo destino y no solo la carpeta donde lo quieres guardar, ya que no es así como funciona.